# how to customize a label when is not in viewdidload?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, label, customization, viewdidload

[I have those variables in collectionviewcell file and I want to change label background and cornerradius but that file doesnt have a viewdidload how can I do that . Thanks for helps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95kZT.png)

Comment: Please post your code rather than pasting image links to it.

Comment: I am sorry for that. I will be careful for next time

Comment: Not a problem, it is your interest also, as other people can take your code and work with it

Comment: You're absolutely right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIView subclasses do not have a viewDidLoad method, instead you use the view's initializer:

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       layoutUI()
   }

   required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: coder)
       layoutUI()
   }

   private func layoutUI() { 
        label.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        label.backgroundColor = .blue
   }
}
```

Comment: But I using stroyboard and collection view is in storyboard.
When I implemented that codes it gave me "'self' used before 'super.init' call"
   and "'self' used in method call 'layoutUI' before 'super.init' call"

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I fixed it. Should work now.

Comment: well, so sorry the error was fixed but its give me new error at "label.layer.cornerRadius = 5".
The error is "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value".
but my label was defined

Comment: Can you please ask this as a different question with the code and provide me with the link?

Comment: I can't ask a new question. because my reputation is very bad

Comment: Anyway Thanks. Thank you for your bits of help